# How to draw a grid and paint the grid corners with a point on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFx and I wanted to know how to draw a grid, where I want to draw points on the grid corners. Should I use a gridpane as a foundation or a linechart ? What are the best classes to use a grid and draw on it ?

Comment: Depends on what you need. `Canvas` would probably be the most performant, unless you need resizing. In case you need resizing it may be best to extend `Pane` and override `layoutChildren` to update `Line`s and `Circle`s. Placed as children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn’t use a GridPane, as its children are not guaranteed to be the same size, only to have their grid cell edges aligned.

A [TilePane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html), however, does guarantee that its cells are the same size.  You can then use a [Group](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html) to combine the TilePane with nodes, such as [Circle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html)s, which are centered on the points between the grid cells using some basic math:

```
public class Grid
extends Application {
    private int rows = 10;
    private int columns = 10;
    private int spacing = 8;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TilePane pane = new TilePane(spacing, spacing);
        pane.setPrefColumns(columns);

        Group group = new Group(pane);

        for (int row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < columns; col++) {
                Circle point = new Circle(2);
                point.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                // x = ((tilewidth + hgap) * col) - (hgap / 2)
                // y = ((tileheight + vgap) * row) - (vgap / 2)
                point.centerXProperty().bind(
                    pane.tileWidthProperty().add(pane.hgapProperty())
                        .multiply(col)
                        .subtract(pane.hgapProperty().divide(2)));
                point.centerYProperty().bind(
                    pane.tileHeightProperty().add(pane.vgapProperty())
                        .multiply(row)
                        .subtract(pane.vgapProperty().divide(2)));
                group.getChildren().add(point);
            }
        }

        // Example grid content
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(row * rows + col));
                pane.getChildren().add(text);
            }
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(group));
        stage.setTitle("Grid");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to connect the points with a line when clicked, what class should I use ? Path, LineTo classes ?

Comment: You certainly could use a Path, but I think a regular standalone [Line](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) would be easier.

Comment: Can I draw the line between the points in the TilePane ? Or should I create a simple pane which has a TilePane in it to draw between points ?

Comment: You will want to add your Lines, or Path, to the Group, not directly to the TilePane.  The TilePane class makes a tile for each child;  you don’t want your lines to actually be laid out as tiles.

Comment: Ok thank you but what I don't understand is how does a point know when to draw a line to another point when clicked ? What I mean is how can I select several points and draw the line ?

Comment: It doesn’t.  You have to add that logic.  You must add a mouse handler to each point, which knows about the coordinates corresponding to that point.  That mouse handle can then create the lines you want.  Selecting several points for drawing a contiguous line requires a private field that remembers which points have been clicked.